# Java compilation / package / namespace error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, package

This is the stupidest, simplest problem ever with basic Java, but what am I doing wrong?

In a directory structure called

```
com/myname/robos
   - Robo.java
   - Arena.java
```

Robo.java :

```
package com.myname.robos;   

public class Robo {
  public void fala() {
    System.out.println("Gleep Beep Boop!");     
  }
}
```

Arena.java :

```
package com.myname.robos;

import com.myname.robos.Robo;

public class Arena {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robo r2 = new Robo();
        r2.fala();
    }
}
```

When I try to :

```
javac Robo.java
```

it compiles.

When I then try to

```
javac Arena.java
```

I get

```
Arena.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
import com.myname.robos.Robo;
                            ^
  symbol:   class Robo
  location: package com.myname.robos
Arena.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Robo r2 = new Robo();
        ^
  symbol:   class Robo
  location: class Arena
Arena.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Robo r2 = new Robo();
                      ^
  symbol:   class Robo
  location: class Arena
3 errors
```

I KNOW it's an error about incompatibility between directory / package etc. names.

But I still never get this right. What *should* I be writing?

Comment: `javac com/myname/robos/Robo.java`, `javac com/myname/robos/Arena.java`, and read up on the `classpath` and `sourcepath` options to `javac`.

Comment: I have to run the compiler from outside the path?

Comment: You have to run it in such a way as to _preserve_ the path. Read the Fine Manual. It's documented how to use `javac`. Read the Fine Manual.

Comment: Thanks. What's the Fine Manual?

Comment: The documentation. It's a general term, popular in programming circles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your files are in the same structure as your package reference, say:

if your .java files are for instance at ../Desktop you must create folders with names: com, myname and robos and then paste them there, so your files will be inside ../Desktop/com/myname/robos.

Then you just need to compile Arena.java and run it:

$ javac com/myname/robos/Arena.java

$ java com/myname/robos/Arena

Positioning you inside ../Desktop

Comment: Not sure what you're indicating as to paths, but it's best not to `javac` from down deep in the package hierarchy as you seem perhaps to be indicating. You want to compile from the root of the package hierarchy or use the `classpath` and/or `sourcepath` options to set it straight. This answer is not correct.

Comment: Ok, you are right, edited. You can compile from the root of the package hierarchy, however, in this case it is needed to establish in javac command the hierarchy itself.

Comment: `java` requires a fully-qualified class name as an argument, not a file system path. What are you indicating with `../Desktop` at the start of those commands? That shouldn't be part of the command. Do you run your examples before posting them?

Comment: It isn't, it is just an example of posible location, it is not part of the javac command

Comment: But you showed it as part of the command. I don't understand.

Comment: Ok, I modified the answer to be specific that ../Desktop is just an example of location, thanks for your feedback :)